# Delphi 10.3 RIO ImageList causes crash on Android 5.1.1

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I recently moved from Delphi Berlin to Delphi Rio since I need the new Android stuff. Trough trial and error I figured out that the ImageList I have in my DataModule is causing a problem - It starts and stays at the Splash Screen.

I've created a new Multi-Device application without anything, put a SpeedButton `(SB_BTN1)` and a ImageList on the main form. Loaded a small BMP image to the ImageList and attached it to the SpeedButton `(SB_BTN1)` - which causes for it to stay on the splash screen and not load.

BUT if I add another SpeedButton `(SB_BTN2)` - and set `(SB_BTN1)` invisible, and on the `(SB_BTN2)` - code I add that it makes the `(SB_BTN1)` visible, the form gets past the loading screen and everything works.

I aswell have attached it to Logcat to see what it says - to no success, it doesn't show any error.

My Andrid SDK API Level is 26 and NDK Level is 14 -- If this helps in any way

EDIT:
Forgot to mention, that the sample: "ImageListDemo" also does this.

EDIT-2: So I aswell tried to do a fresh install - I reseted my whole pc, and I upgraded from 10.3 to 10.3.1 - still the same problem.

Comment: The ImageListDemo starts OK on my Lenovo Tab 3 (TB3-710F) with Android 5.0.1, using 10.3.2. SDK API level is set to 28, NDK version r17b set to API level 22

Comment: @DaveNottage Reset my SDK to level 28, and NDK version to r17b, set API level to API 22. On Android 5.1.1 - Still doesn't work, but if I do the same settings on Android 5.1 - It works